# Update a user with forwarding email address in Google Apps Gmail

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

Is there a provision in the Admin (or other) APIs for patching/creating/updating a user to include a forwarding address or addresses?  I can't see it in the Admin API section for users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with the Email Settings API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_forwarding_settings